# Primeng : inputSwitch reference boolean from object

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm using angular 7.2.0 and primeng 7.0.0, i'm trying to use p-inputSwitch and reference the boolean from an object as shown below, but the switch is always unchecked even with true values :

```
<div *ngFor="let t of tasks">
     <p-inputSwitch (ngModel)="t.important" > </p-inputSwitch>
</div>
```

componenent :

```
tasks: Task[];

constructor() {
    this.tasks = [
      { name: 'task 1', important: false },
      { name: 'task 2', important: true },
      { name: 'task 3', important: true }
    ];
}

export interface Task {
   name: string;
   important: boolean;
}
```

Comment: Try changing this `(ngModel)` to this `[(ngModel)]`.

Comment: no this doesn't work with [(ngModel)] i get the error : Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'p-inputSwitch'.

Comment: Then you probably need to make sure that the FormsModule is imported in your application.

Comment: that's right the FormsModule was missing, now it works, thank you